# Preprocess Vue components with custom Webpack loader

Tags: vue.js, webpack

I have a Vue component in which I'd like to replace some texts with a custom Webpack loader. My Webpack config:

```
{
    test: /\.vue$/,
    use: ["custom-loader"]
}
```

The problem is that I get the following error:

```
Error: [VueLoaderPlugin Error] No matching use for vue-loader is found.
Make sure the rule matching .vue files include vue-loader in its use.
```

But if I add `vue-loader` to the `use` array it still doesn't work, custom-loader doesn't catch the `.vue` files.

Is there any solution for this?